# Could a human be captured in a web?

Tags: insects, insectoid

Could an arthropod or similar creature make a web, using silk and other arthropodal secretions, that is large, strong, sticky enough to entrap a human that walks into it? The creature would be bound by the normal real rules of biology, at least in terms of what it puts into the web

Comment: [Retiarius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retiarius). His usual adversary was the heavily armed [secutor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secutor). The match was considered well balanced.

Comment: @AlexP So, were the spider to secrete hemp fibers and the weights for the net, then it would be possible ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a yes. Like are there is more to it than just that? Because obviously yes. You can simply scale what works for other animals and it would work for us. 
Like are you asking a net that is immune to most hand held tools attempts to destroy it? Or what. Like I feel there must be more to this question

Comment: I suspect the bigger problem will be how to get arthropods, which can't get that big outside of the sea, to make such a huge (relatively) investment in sophisticated human-capture equipment. But physically, I can't think of why not. Maybe something like a social insect with a trap-pit for large animals lined with poisonous webs to disable large prey animals. Then eat them slowly while still alive and paralyzed. I think you're asking the wrong question - like "why?"

Comment: tensile strength of spider thread is 1.2GPa more than 2x of hardened steel so you need an army size that shoot tsunami of these silks to incapacitate people, that would be a sight to behold imagine millions of these critters having explosive diarrhea at the same time... if you insist solo then go for big butt hole!

Comment: @user6760 tensile strength, maybe. Resistance to shearing stress and toughness - way lower - carry a knife to get out of the predicament.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it doesn't take much to get tangled and trapped into something, especially if you are not fully focused on not getting trapped and you have nothing or nobody at hand to help you get free.

Have you ever seen how fishermen work carefully when repairing their fishing nets, and how easy is to get stuck into them when not moving carefully? Well, I often did as a child. And those nets were not sticky, which puts an additional obstacle.

I also often stopped seeing how preys get trapped into spiderwebs: it's not the falling in the net that traps them, it's the rolling around to get free that entangle them. Sometimes I have seen an insect walk away effortlessly, just because instead of panicking and rolling, it just kept walking and luckily stumbled on the non sticky fibers.